# Selectively adding values of columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas data frame like this

```
YEAR_OPENED  2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009
 1999          1    0    0   0    1    0     0   0     1    0
 2000          1    1    2   0    3    0     0   0     0    0
 2001          0    0    0   4    0    0     0   0     0    0
```

I want to add all the values in the given columns like this:

```
YEAR_OPENED   CLOSED_IN_5_YEARS
 1999               2
 2000               7
 2001               4
```

So basically I want to check if the column names fall in a five year range of the corresponding values in the column 'YEAR_OPENED' and create a new column with the sum of all the values. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['CLOSED_IN_5_YEARS'] = df.set_index('YEAR_OPENED').apply(
        lambda x: sum(i for i, c in zip(x, x.index) if x.name <= int(c) <= x.name + 5), axis=1
    ).values

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   YEAR_OPENED  2000  2001  2002  ...  2007  2008  2009  CLOSED_IN_5_YEARS
0         1999     1     0     0  ...     0     1     0                  2
1         2000     1     1     2  ...     0     0     0                  7
2         2001     0     0     0  ...     0     0     0                  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `iloc` to select the specific columns based on variable `n`, and the `concat` with the first column:

```
n=5
df['CLOSED_IN_5_YEARS'] = df.iloc[:,1:n+1].sum(axis=1)
df=pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,-1]], axis=1)
df
Out[1]: 
   YEAR_OPENED  CLOSED_IN_5_YEARS
0         1999                  2
1         2000                  7
2         2001                  4
```